# How to get data from a URL inside a rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

I have a controller method say

```
def my_method
 @gibbon = <data needed>
 render :something
end
```

and i have a URL say

```
http://exampleforme.com/example1
```

which returns a certain text, how to get this text inside my controller method from the URL?

I am using rails 2.8

Comment: I think you probably need to expand your explanation of what you are looking for...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `Net::HTTP` to get that URL as a string:

```ruby
@gibbon = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://exampleforme.com/example1"))
```

See the [API docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Net/HTTP/get/class) for more information.

Note: that this could impact your response time if that URL is slow to respond.

Answer (score -2):

can you show me your route file ?

but I think if you want "example1" text in url you can call params[:id] in your controller

```
@text = params[:id]
```